# How many times can i charge iPad2 Battery?

Tags: ipad

I want to know how many times can i charge iPad2 Battery.
I heard that iPad Battery can recharge 1000 times.
if recharge 1000 times over,that battery will be damage.
Is that right?
Please tell me about ipad battery.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a [great page on batteries](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipad.html) and it does say that they are designed to still have 80% of their capacity remaining after 1000 charge cycles.

Not all batteries are perfect, so you could have problems even on the second charge. Heat, always having it charged and deep discharge can also cause them to fail or wear out before you get to 1000 charges.

Don't confuse an isolated failure or anecdotal evidence for the overall statistics for a million devices seen as a group. Also, damage like wetness or other failures of the electronics can bring down a perfect battery so it's hard to know what might cause a specific failure without taking it apart.

Comment: Not to get bogged down in detail, but it says that they're designed to have **up to** 80% remaining after 1K charge cycles.

Comment: My experience is most units far exceed the design threshold. That doesn't mean many thousands of people end up with batteries that don't work as designed and require early service. Your sentence is a perfect one line answer ;-)

Answer (score -3):

I have been using a the battery in my ipad for ten years and I still get a good 8 hours out of it :-)

Comment: Hee hee. Must be some fine stories you can tell about having the oldest iPad on the planet.